# Getting data from tables with foreign keys C# entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have this classes in Code First asp.net

```
public class Account
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        public string AccountTitle { get; set; }
        public Classification Classification { get; set; }
    }

    public class Classification 
    { 
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        public string TitleClassification { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    }

    public class ClassificationDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string TitleClassification { get; set; }
    }
```

In my Db Context

```
public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
```

AccountingManager.FindAll is this

```
public IQueryable<T> FindAll()
        {
            return context.Set<T>().AsNoTracking().AsQueryable();
        }
```

I am trying to get just the "Classification" which is just 3 but I am getting the "Account" that is associated with it too with this code:

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route("get-classification")]
        [Authorize]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAccountClassification()
        {
            List<ClassificationDto> classificationList = new List<ClassificationDto>();

            var accountingManager = new AccountingManager(context);

            var list = accountingManager.FindAll();

            classificationList = await list.Select(s => new ClassificationDto
            {
                Id = s.Classification.Id,
                TitleClassification = s.Classification.TitleClassification,
            }).ToListAsync();

            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK, classificationList);
        }
```

This is how it is in my table
[image]

Comment: You need to get all data from Classification table? Or you need only data that associated with Accounts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get all rows from Classification table,

add `public DbSet<Classification> Classifications { get; set;}` property to your `DbContext` class. And then implement similar to `FindAll()` method:

```
return context.Classifications.AsNoTracking().ToList()
```